# Sending Data from Client to Server APIs

Tags: java, spring, angular, hibernate

I have a class that has other classes as its data members. The class model can be found in another post [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/182105/coupon-platform-coupon-promo-domain-model). It has many data members so i took some of the members to create other classes. My application consists of Spring Server APIs with Hibernate and the client side is in Angular 2x.

On the client side i will have something like a form that will contain all the data members that users will fill and send to the server back-end.

A) I am planning to send the data in JSON that is key-value pairs.
   Is there a better way to do it?

B) Should i create the same class structure on the client side also before i send data to the server?

B)What i am struggling with now is how to reconstruct the data on the server side when client send them) and use them to initialize my class (eg. **Coupon** class) before i save them to the database.

For instance if a user wants to create a **Coupon**, how do i use the data from the client to initialize the **coupon** class before i store them in the database since **Coupon** has other classes as its data members.

For example the signature of the method to create Coupon will look like this on the server side

**public ResponseEntity createCoupon(@RequestBody Coupon coupon ){}**

If i send the data as JSON's key-value pair, i don't think the Coupon parameter in this function is going to be initialized. It also contains other classes as data members.

It is my first time dealing with this kind of situation so i need some guidelines, good pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A) I am planning to send the data in JSON that is key-value pairs. Is there a better way to do it?

Yes. The much better way is send data as a JSON structure similar to your 
`Coupon/Product/Promo` graph. And serialize/deserialize it using Jackson.

> B) Should i create the same class structure on the client side also before i send data to the server?

Yes. You can even use similar `classes` in JavaScript.

> B)What i am struggling with now is how to reconstruct the data on the server side when client send them) and use them to initialize my class (eg. Coupon class) before i save them to the database.

The best (at least good way) exists to do that. It depends on your context: business requirements, your skills, even your team. There are some advices:

Use a separate model graph (with `DTO`) to serialize/deserialize `JSON`. It is a bit harder. But you can have a very-hard-to-implement sudden requirement in the future.

You need to experiment and choose the right way. So you can start from the simplest case

```
class CouponModel {

  String onlineCode;

  List<String> productIds;

}
```

When you get `CouponModel` from the client side you will need:
create `Coupon` and get/load products by ids (it is a good place to validate product ids).

The other option:

```
class CouponModel {

  String onlineCode;

  List<ProductModel> products;

}
```

`ProductModel` have only id for `client side` -> `server side` and have full product data fro `server side` -> `client side`.

Answer (score -1):

A) JSON object is standard for working with APIs, often `req.body` is literally an object, though it's not limited to a JSON object.

B/C) This is all about yours and your client's preferences. The front and back will both be handled separately as far as class definitions typically go, but best practice is to create a class structure for re-used objects to ensure the data is handled exactly as expected. It's a solid fail-safe and a good practice to follow, but it is not a requirement.

Note: A solid example of front/back class construction for an API using full typescript front and back (angular/node) can be found here: https://github.com/DavideViolante/Angular-Full-Stack

Comment: Actually there really isn't such a thing as a JSON object

Comment: @charlietfl a JSON.stringified Object is what is implied